# How do I make the android alarm work?

Tags: alarm, clock, date-and-time

My alarm clock stops working every now and then. I would say about once a month it will just stop sounding alarms. Sometimes the next day it will start working again, sometimes not. In googling it looks like there are a ton of people with similar issues and lots of people just saying to kill the app or clear the cache.

All the proposed solutions I read are after-the-fact fixes. I.E. once the problem happens then you fix it. I would like to find a solution that prevents this happening in the first place (I don't want to have to be late for work in order to know when my alarm needs fixing).

Anyone know what is going on here? It's the default clock app on a nexus 9 (i.e. vanilla android). I believe I also had the same issue with my Xoom, Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 though. It's been going on for years (heaven forbid google responds to user feedback).

I am thinking I might just have to switch to a third party app, but ugh.

Comment: Have you tried any third parthy apps yet..? Try this [Timely Alarm Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely&hl=en) if the default app issue persists..

Comment: Thanks @Lucky I have actually used that app in the past and liked it. I can't remember what prompted me to stop. I feel like maybe I had the same issue. Maybe I am just a heavy sleeper. I was thinking it would be nice if I had an app that logged my attempts to snooze and dismiss alarms. I started using "My Morning Routine" which is actually a really cool full featured ad-free alarm app. And bonus, it offers a little bit of logging (avg time to dismiss). I can set it up to launch a tasker task on dismiss for some full logging too (just thought of that but it does have tasker support built in)